# gulp - combine multiple transformations into one

Tags: gulp

Let me say, I have two gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('pug', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(cache(pug()))
    // ---- begin ---
    .pipe(some_action1())
    .pipe(some_action2())
    .pipe(some_action3());
    // ---- end ---
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    // ---- begin ---
    .pipe(some_action1())
    .pipe(some_action2())
    .pipe(some_action3());
    // ---- end ---
});
```

Code clone for some_action1/2/3 makes me so sad. So I want change them to something like:

```
all_actions = /* do some_action1, some_action2, and, some_action3 */({/* ??? */});

gulp.task('pug', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(cache(pug()))
    .pipe(all_actions());
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(all_actions());
});
```

What is the *gulp* way to do so, and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the task functions with pipes and all and call it using [gulp-merge](https://github.com/teambition/merge2), where we can merge two sets of pipes by means of::

```
merge(pipes_1, pipes_2)
```

**The code**

```
var gulpMerge = require('gulp-merge');

gulp.task('pug', function () {

    return gulpMerge(gulp.src('src/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(cache(pug())), allActions('src/**/*.pug'));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {

    return allActions('src/**/*.pug');
});


function allActions(source){
    return gulp.src(source)
        // ---- begin ---
        .pipe(some_action1())
        .pipe(some_action2())
        .pipe(some_action3());
        // ---- end ---
}
```

Furthermore, instead of combining pipes you can maintain the granularity of your tasks, keep them small and specialized by calling them from an all actions task as dependency tasks.

Say you have task_1, task_2, and task_3. Say that task: *someActions* needs task_1 and task_2, and task *allActions* needs all three tasks. Then you can have:

```
gulp.task('someActions', ['task_1', 'task_2']);

gulp.task('allActions', ['task_1', 'task_2', 'task_3']);
```